# SQL schema for product translations

Tags: sql, postgresql, localization, translation

I have a product entity, each entity have multiple fields such as:

`price`, `user_id` - the user who created this product, `name` and so on.

Some products are added by me, (the administrator) and are public to all the other users. **BUT**, products created by the user are non public by default (leaving a scalable open if I'll ever want to allow user products to be translated and public for other users to view).

**My goal:**
I need to be able to select products with the correct user's language, and if a translation is not found, use the default name. This needs to work in a system where users are free to add their own products.

So far I've come up with a possible schema, but the only thing that's bugging me is possible redundant name data for the same language (feel free to add up to that). The `name` field on `product` table might collide with the `products_translations` table since I have no idea what's the original `name` language.
For example, I can still insert an english translation for products `1 & 2` (The same way I can insert a Spanish translation for product `3`).

Schema with base records:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  language_id int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE products (
  product_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id int,
  public boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
  price decimal(12, 2) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE languages (
  language_Id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  code varchar(2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE products_translations (
  product_id int NOT NULL,
  language_id int NOT NULL,
  translation varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (product_id, language_id)
);

ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT u_lid_fk FOREIGN KEY (language_id) 
REFERENCES languages (language_id);

ALTER TABLE products ADD CONSTRAINT uid_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) 
REFERENCES users (user_id);

ALTER TABLE products_translations ADD CONSTRAINT pt_pid_fk FOREIGN KEY (product_id) 
REFERENCES products (product_id);

ALTER TABLE products_translations ADD CONSTRAINT pt_lid_fk FOREIGN KEY (language_id) 
REFERENCES languages (language_id);

-- Base data:

INSERT INTO languages (code) VALUES ('en'), ('es');
INSERT INTO users (language_id) VALUES (1), (2);

-- Admin inserted foods
INSERT INTO products (user_id, public, price, name)
VALUES (NULL, true, 400, 'Phone'), (NULL, true, 2, 'Drink'),
       (NULL, true, 1.5, 'queso'), (NULL, true, 2, 'Ball');

INSERT INTO products_translations (product_id, language_id, translation)
VALUES (1, 2, 'teléfono'), (2, 2, 'bebida'), (3, 1, 'Cheese');

-- User inserted foods
INSERT INTO products (user_id, public, price, name)
VALUES (1, false, 3, 'Phone case');
```

Example select:

```
SELECT 
  p.product_id,
  language_id, 
  price,
  COALESCE(translation, name) AS name
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN products_translations pt ON pt.product_id = p.product_id
  AND pt.language_id = (SELECT language_id FROM users WHERE user_id = 1)
WHERE (p.user_id = 1 OR p.user_id IS NULL) OR public = true
ORDER BY p.product_id
```

This yields:

```
| product_id | language_id  | price | name       | 
|------------|--------------|-------|------------|
| 1          | null         | 400   | Phone      |
| 2          | null         | 2     | Drink      |
| 3          | 1            | 1.5   | Cheese     |
| 4          | null         | 2     | Ball       |
| 5          | null         | 3     | Phone case |
```

Change the `user_id` to `2` (This user's language is Spanish):

```
| product_id | language_id  | price | name       | 
|------------|--------------|-------|------------|
| 1          | 2            | 400   | teléfono   |
| 2          | 2            | 2     | bebida     |
| 3          | null         | 1.5   | queso      |
| 4          | null         | 2     | Ball       |
```

1. Ball is in English because there's no translation provided.
2. The fifth record is not there because product `5` "belongs" to user `1` and its not public.

Finally, is it fine to leave it like this where the name and translation might collide and there might be redundant data? Is there a different better solution?

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/379c3/1)

Any insights are much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think the `user_id` doen't belong in the `products` table.

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks for the reply. But then, how can I differentiate between different users who created different products? See 'Phone case' for example. user 1 should see it but user 2 shouldn't. (unless its public, or the user_id is null - stating that its a general product that doesn't relate to a specific user and any one can view)

Comment: In that case (public being False), you'd need a Junction table (users_products) to register which products can be *seen* by which users. And currently, the the product.names are duplicated (per user) which is rather costly. BTW: what does `public` mean? And: is it a property of a product?

Comment: Currently, your `public` flag is a kind of copy of `(products.user_id IS NULL)`. Your current model will duplicate the product's properties {name,price} (and create a new `product.id` !) if two or more users happen to *possess* the same product. This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @wildplasser Correct, `public` is a field of `product`. Its a bit confusing because you are correct, `public` is kind of a copy of `products.user_id IS NULL) because for me, a `null` `user_id` states that its a general product which anyone can view. **but**, later on I'd might want to allow users to make their products public (only for "accurate" products, for example based on some kind of rating system that detects if a users product is "accurate" or not).  Therefore I believe it is necessary :/

Comment: About your other insight, `If two or more users happen to possess the same product` I'm not sure I fully understood it, but A product can be owned by one or none users. So a duplicate product may occur but it will have different `user_id`'s. I think its okay because a product may be the same but still have some differences. If I'm unclear about something, please let me know and I'll try to explain it better. thanks.

Comment: wrt `is_public`: that's why I kept it.

Answer (score 1):

- the `user_id` should not be an attribute of products
- instead: create a junction table
- *visibility* of a product depends on both `is_public` and existence in the junction-table
- `public` is a keyword in Postgres, better not use it as an identifier.
- for extra fun and convenience I created a table-returning function.

---

```
        -- Create junction table for 'private' products
        -- ---------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE users_products
        ( user_id integer not null references users(user_id)
        , product_id integer not null references products(product_id)
        , PRIMARY KEY (user_id, product_id)
        , UNIQUE (product_id, user_id) -- forces an extra index to be created.
        );

        -- Populate the junction table
        -- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO users_products(user_id,product_id)
SELECT user_id,product_id
FROM products
WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL
-- AND is_public is False
        ;

SELECT * FROM users_products;

        -- Remove redundancy
        -- ---------------------
ALTER TABLE products
        DROP COLUMN user_id
        ;

        -- Check if user_id=1 gets the correct data
        -- ------------------------------------------
SELECT
  p.product_id
  , p.price
  , p.is_public
  , p.name AS orig_name
  , COALESCE(pt.translation, p.name) AS xlat_name
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT u.user_id, pt.product_id, pt.translation
        FROM products_translations pt
        JOIN users u ON u.language_id = pt.language_id
        ) pt ON pt.product_id = p.product_id AND pt.user_id = 1
WHERE p.is_public = True
        OR EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM users_products up
        WHERE up.product_id = p.product_id
        AND up.user_id = 1
        )
ORDER BY p.product_id
        ;

        -- Check if user_id=1 gets the correct data
        -- pack user,product,translation into a CTE
        -- -----------------------------------------
-- EXPLAIN
WITH upl AS (
        SELECT u.user_id, p.product_id, pt.translation
        FROM users u
        CROSS JOIN products p
        LEFT JOIN products_translations pt
                ON pt.language_id = u.language_id
                AND pt.product_id = p.product_id
        WHERE u.user_id = 1
        )
SELECT
  p.product_id
  , p.price
  , p.is_public AS is_public
  , p.name AS orig_name
  , COALESCE(upl.translation, p.name) AS xlat_name
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN upl ON upl.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE p.is_public = True
        OR EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM users_products up
        WHERE up.product_id = p.product_id
        AND up.user_id = upl.user_id
        )
        ;
        -- Extra fun: put the complete CTE-query into a table-returning function
        -- ------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE FUNCTION products_for_user(_user_id integer)
RETURNS setof products AS
$func$
WITH upl AS (
        SELECT u.user_id, p.product_id, pt.translation
        FROM users u
        CROSS JOIN products p
        LEFT JOIN products_translations pt
                ON pt.language_id = u.language_id
                AND pt.product_id = p.product_id
        WHERE u.user_id = _user_id
        )
SELECT
  p.product_id AS product_id
  , p.is_public AS is_public
  , p.price AS price
  , COALESCE(upl.translation, p.name) AS name
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN upl ON upl.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE p.is_public = True
        OR EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM users_products up
        WHERE up.product_id = p.product_id
        AND up.user_id = upl.user_id
        )
        ;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE SECURITY INVOKER ROWS 300 -- COST 1
        ;

        -- Call the function
    -- uid=1: English, 5 products
    -- uid=2: Spanish, 4 products
    -- --------------------------
SELECT *
FROM products_for_user(1)
        ;

SELECT *
FROM products_for_user(2)
        ;
```

---

Result:

---

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
 user_id | product_id 
---------+------------
       1 |          5
(1 row)

ALTER TABLE
 product_id | price  | is_public | orig_name  | xlat_name  
------------+--------+-----------+------------+------------
          1 | 400.00 | t         | Phone      | Phone
          2 |   2.00 | t         | Drink      | Drink
          3 |   1.50 | t         | queso      | Cheese
          4 |   2.00 | t         | Ball       | Ball
          5 |   3.00 | f         | Phone case | Phone case
(5 rows)

 product_id | price  | is_public | orig_name  | xlat_name  
------------+--------+-----------+------------+------------
          1 | 400.00 | t         | Phone      | Phone
          2 |   2.00 | t         | Drink      | Drink
          3 |   1.50 | t         | queso      | Cheese
          4 |   2.00 | t         | Ball       | Ball
          5 |   3.00 | f         | Phone case | Phone case
(5 rows)

CREATE FUNCTION
 product_id | is_public | price  |    name    
------------+-----------+--------+------------
          1 | t         | 400.00 | Phone
          2 | t         |   2.00 | Drink
          3 | t         |   1.50 | Cheese
          4 | t         |   2.00 | Ball
          5 | f         |   3.00 | Phone case
(5 rows)

 product_id | is_public | price  |   name   
------------+-----------+--------+----------
          1 | t         | 400.00 | teléfono
          2 | t         |   2.00 | bebida
          3 | t         |   1.50 | queso
          4 | t         |   2.00 | Ball
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed response (loved that "extra fun" part lol +1). I'll change the column name from `public`. And I have a few questions. 1. Is a cross join okay for performance in the case? lets say the products table will have 10m rows, 2. Why do you use a cross join? I don't have much experience with it. 3. How would I correctly return the language code? 4. I understand your answer fixes a different problem with my schema, but still, it doesn't fixes the original problem where there might be an English translation for id `5`. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cny2pD9LQdJDVAKigVgBjX/2

Comment: 5. What does `STABLE SECURITY INVOKER ROWS 300 -- COST 1` mean? 6. What does the unique index actually do? 7. Why do you think the `user_id` better off separated to `users_products`? If the requirement is each product can be owned by one or none users, and if its public (or doesn't belong to anyone) then its viewable by anyone? Again, thank you very much!

Comment: 1,2) In this case the cross-join is restricted by the `user_id = 1`, so it is mostly harmless. And there is no actual join-condition, since the product_translations needs to be LEFT-joined. 3) You could extract the language_id in the CTE, it would need changing the return type, too. 5) it is all in the data. If you add an English translation to the products_translations table, it will be selected, if needed. (you could also add the foriginal language to the products table) 1,2) check the resulting query plan!

Comment: 1,2 I checked the query plan, understood. 3. I'll check that out 5. I believe you wanted to refer to 4, and yep, the select looks perfect, I'm just thinking it might be redundant having a product name in English and then being able to provide an English translation without any constraints. No.5 refers to `STABLE SECURITY` 6. I still don't understand why add another unique index if there's already a compound primary? 7. You wrote a very detailed answer regarding the change for a junction table, but I'm no sure why its needed in the case? (view my previous comment stating the "requirement").

Comment: `If the requirement is each product can be owned by one or none users,` <<-- is a strange requirement, IMHO. You can switch back to your original model, but multiple users could insert exactly the same product under a different `id`. [be my guest!]

Comment: 6) for N<-->M junction tables, it is always advisable to have the composite index *both ways*, both sides need to be joined to other tables sometimes. (both elements are FK's)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236323/discussion-between-ofek-and-wildplasser).

Comment: No. I don't chat. Ive given enough feedback for you to solve your problem [ := data modelling]

Comment: Sure, thank you very much. Using your insights on the topic I'll try to find the correct schema for my use-case.

Comment: Although you've provided me a lot of help, my question was finally answered by Gordon Linoff's comment. Even though, I must thank you because your answer did help me with other questions I had. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

> the only thing that's bugging me is possible redundant name data for the same language (feel free to add up to that). The name field on product table might collide with the products_translations table since I have no idea what's the original name language.

Your data model doesn't have the language of the `name` column in `products`.  Apparently the name is language-less.

If you care about the name and want to treat it specially, then you have two options:

1. Store the language in `products`.
2. Remove the name entirely and depend only on translations at the product level.

I should also note that nothing in your data model prevents two products from having the same name, but different translations.  The translations are at the product level not the name level.

These issues do not particularly bother me.  What you really need depends on your particular use-case.  For instance, the `name` might always be in English, so you might not want an English translation.  Or, you might want the default language to be product specific, in which case you would have a language in the product (but no `name`).

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your reply. Let me explain why (I think I need a "language-less" name in `products`). Because a user might insert a product and name it however he wants (the language is unknown because I don't wish to ask the user for the language when he's creating it) then I can't go with your first option (storing the `language_id` in `products`). Your second suggestion is interesting because as I said before what should I do with the case above? create an "unknown" language and when inserting the product also insert an unknown translation with that language?

Comment: @Ofek . . . If the language is unknown for the `products` table, then it should only be used as a last resort when there are no translations available.

Comment: Correct, so if I have a name column in `products` and the name's language is unknown, ill use it as a last resort. My question is: is it fine that this current schema makes it possible to provide an English translation to a product even though that product `name` may be already in English? I am asking that because its seems like data duplication/wrong schema model?

Comment: @Ofek . . . It is fine because the product name is not "in English".  You don't know that.  The database doesn't know that.  It is merely a string that whoever created or updated the row chose to put on the product.